# PHP sprintf space padding

Tags: php, padding, space

I have the following line in my code which displays my output in 6 characters with leading zeros.

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%06d", $phpPartHrsMls);
```

I want to replace the leading zeros with spaces.  Have tried all the examples found by searching this site and others and cannot figure it out.

Here are some I have tried:

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%6s", $phpPartHrsMls);

$formatted_value = printf("[%6s]\n",    $phpPartHrsMls); // right-justification with spaces
```

Comment: What is an example of `$phpPartHrsMls`?

Comment: This should work if you output to a file or stdout. In the browser — as Niet the Dark Absol correctly mentioned — spaces have different semantics and you might be better off using a `<table>`.

Comment: Its number output - 300

Comment: Looks like it works: http://codepad.org/Kn0hlxQV Note that `printf()` outputs the value and returns the string length, hence the `'9'` at the end.

Comment: I am echoing this textout line in my code...not sure where to insert the php_eol;...I tried a few variations and no luck...<td style=\"padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;\">".$formatted_value."</td>

Comment: @JaredFarrish..see comment above.  I am echoing a table of data and this is one of the <td>s. I tried adding this code too and it did not work...$formatted_value = sprintf("%6s", $phpPartHrsMls);
    $formatted_value2 = $formatted_value.PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 7):

In the browser, spaces will always be collapsed.

Try:

```
<pre><?php echo $formatted_value; ?></pre>
```

And once you're satisfied with that, take a look at the CSS `white-space:pre-wrap` - a very useful property!

Answer (score 5):

This will align the left with spaces:

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%6s", $phpPartHrsMls);
echo "<pre>" . $formatted_value . "</pre>";
```

This will align the right with spaces:

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%-6s", $phpPartHrsMls);
echo "<pre>" . $formatted_value . "</pre>";
```

If you want to print only six digits, and others to remove:

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%-6.6s", $phpPartHrsMls);
echo "<pre>" . $formatted_value . "</pre>";
```

One more thing, the browser will generally ignore the spaces, so it's better to wrap your output in `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Changing leading zeroes to leading spaces:

```
$formatted_value = sprintf("%' 6s", $phpPartHrsMls);
```

Comment: This works for the command line which is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```php
str_pad($phpPartHrsMls, 6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `%06d` please try some larger number .

your code can some thing like below try :

```
printf('%20.2f', $phpPartHrsMls);
```

and you can use `&nbsp;` for space on your html .